# How do I process events on a QThread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, events

Normally if I am in a process intensive function I can call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` or `QEventLoop::processEvents()` to ensure that my processing doesn't block other signals and slots.

However, if I create a new `QThread` and move a worker to that thread, then I don't have a `QCoreApplication` or a `QEventLoop` with which to call `processEvents()`.

From my research, it seems that I should be able to install a `QEventLoop` on the new `QThread` I created, and then I can call `processEvents()` on that `QEventLoop`.

However, I can't figure out how to do this. I figure it might look something like this:

```
QThread *thread = new QThread(this);
Worker *worker = new Worker(this);
QEventLoop *loop = new QEventLoop();

connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(startProcessing()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(done()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(done()), loop, SLOT(quit()));

worker->moveToThread(thread);    

//loop->exec() // blocks processing of this thread
loop->moveToThread(thread);

//loop->exec() // loop is not a member of this thread anymore and even
               // if it was, this would block the thread from starting
thread->start();
//loop->exec(); // loop is not a member of this thread anymore and even
                // if it was, this would block this thread from continuing
```

Every place I try to start the loop has some sort of issue. But even if something like this worked, how would I call `processEvents()` on that `QEventLoop()`?

Alternatively, `QThread` also has a function `setEventDispatcher()` and `QAbstractEventDispatcher` has a `processEvents()` function, but I can't seem to find anything that subclasses `QAbstractEventDispatcher`.

What is the proper way to process events during an intensive worker function on a `QThread`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the documentation, calling `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` processes events for whichever thread called it.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I thought that to use `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` I would have to create a new `QCoreApplication`. But it appears that my `QThread` is still a part of the preexisting `QCoreApplication`.

Answer (score -6):

> However, if I create a new `QThread` and move a worker to that thread, then I don't have a `QCoreApplication` or a `QEventLoop` with which to call `processEvents()`.

Exactly - don't call it. You don't need it, you don't want it.